# Unable to upload attatchments over the Jira API

Tags: perl, jira, jira-rest-api

I've seen the question asked a few times but no real answer. The [Jira::Rest](https://metacpan.org/pod/JIRA::REST) module appears to be out of date since username and password is not an accepted authentication method.

I am unable to add attachments via perl. My first attempt was using REST::Client with LWP::useragent. Example below

```
    my $client = REST::Client->new();
    $client->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' . $config_yaml->{auth}
    $client->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $client->addHeader('X_Atlassian_Token', 'no-check');
    $client->addHeader('Content' => [ file => [ $filename ],  ]);
    my $file_sent = $client->POST("issue/$ticket/attachments");

    my $response =  $file_sent->responseContent();
```

For some reason the response was an empty string.

I thought maybe I was missing something so I tried with a curl request

```
curl --request POST --url 'https://cloudurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/[ticket_id]/attachments' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' --header "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" \
--header 'Authorization: Basic [api auth string]' \
-F "file=@test_file_upload.txt"
```

The curl request returned the expected message and the ticket had the attachment. So I tried again using just LWP::UserAgent.

```
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->timeout(10);
    $ua->env_proxy;
    $ua->default_header('Accept' => 'application/json');
    $ua->default_header('X-Atlassian-Token' => 'no-check');
    $ua->default_header('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $config_yaml->{auth});

    my $response = $ua->post($url, Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
        Content => [
            field => [$filename],
        ],
    );
    warn $response->is_success;
    warn $response->decoded_content;
```

For some reason this returned 200 and an empty just like when I tried with Rest::Client. I believe the URL and parts of it are correct.

If  X-Atlassian-Token is ommitted I get the error specified in the documentation and if I send no content I get an error complaining about that missing. Is there something missing from my request when I make it via LWP::UserAgent or REST::Client that causes me to get no response?

For reference this is the part of the api documentation I have been trying to work from.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-attachments/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-attachments-post

The parts discussed on the atlassian support area do not seem to have a solution for this either.

Comment: The examples in the linked API documentation provide an `<api_token>` that seems to be missing in your request.

Comment: @jo-37 Ah yeah your right it is missing from the REST::Client example. I have it set as a header earlier in the code. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access on the box, I'd use `tcpdump -A -s2048 host cloudurl.atlassian.net` and look for any differences between the successful curl and the other messages.

https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=464442 suggests using

```
print $response->headers_as_string;
```

or

```
print join "\n", $file_sent->->responseHeader($_) for $file_sent->->responseHeaders();
```

to see what you're getting back.